# date converting via XMLHttpRequest

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to convert the date value that I pull from tumblr archive into a text format. Currently it will show in numeric date format, eg:

- 2015/1
- 2015/2
- etc

However, I want to look like this:

- January 2015
- February 2015
- etc

Is there a third party script or way to do this using jquery? or am I stuck with it looking like this? Below is the code:

```
jQuery(function($) {
  var xhr;
  xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xhr.open('GET', '/archive', true);
  xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {
    var $ul, months;
    if (xhr.readyState === 4 && xhr.status === 200) {
      $('#monthly-archive').replaceWith('<ul id="monthly-archive"  class="list-unstyled" />');
      months = $(xhr.responseText).find('.months > ul > li:not(.empty)');
      $ul = $('#monthly-archive');
      return months.each(function() {
        var count, ym, ym_str;
        ym = $(this).find('a').attr('href');
        ym_str = ym.replace(/\/archive\//, '');
        count = $(this).find('span').html();
        return $ul.prepend("<li><a href=\"" + ym + "\">" + ym_str + " (" + count + ")</a></li>");
      });
    }
  };
  return xhr.send(null);
});
```

Comment: http://momentjs.com/

Comment: @azium and how would I integrate it?

Comment: So I'm staring at your code, and I'm failing to see where the date is coming from. Which variable contains the date?

Comment: yeah! ym_str - is where I collect it from. It's for tumblr usage

Comment: `how would I integrate it` ...by reading the documentation

Answer (score 1):

If you know the format it'd be easy to convert it with a simple function. For 2015/1 format:

```
var months = ["January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June", "July", "August", "September", "October", "November", "December"];

function convertDate(dt) {
    var da = dt.split('/');
    return months[da[1] - 1] + " " + da[0];
}
```

[**jsfiddle DEMO**](https://jsfiddle.net/samuraii/49zfmqdL/)

Answer (score 0):

Somewhere along the way in your code you're going to get a date string of some kind. In JavaScript you can create a `Date` object by passing the date string as an argument. Try opening up the console (F12) and typing:

```
new Date('2015/4/30')
```

and you'll get:

```
Thu Apr 30 2015 00:00:00 GMT-0400 (EDT)
```

If you return the date object to a variable you can access methods of the date object like `getMonth()`

```
var date = new Date('2015/4/30')
console.log(date.getMonth()) // 3, because January is 0
```

Using a library like momentjs, you can format these dates further.
Firstly, include moment

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.10.2/moment.js"></script>
```

Then pass the date object to moment and use the format method:

```
moment(new Date('2015/4/30')).format('MMMM YYYY'); // 'April 2015'
```